# is it unsafe to use Thread in android?

Tags: java, android

I used a service to start a Thread, in this thread, I wrote a while loop(I set a flag, while flag is true, the thread runs, if the flag is false, then the thread won't do anything, thus stop the thread manually) in this thread. when I debug my code, I often noticed that the thread is over, but the service was still running. Is it recycled by android system?

How can I do to prevent my thread from recycling?

====== EDIT =======

"will by thread be cleaned up by the system automatically before it ends" - means the thread is being killed when it shouldn't be

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Perhaps you should include some code to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: Recycling means 'garbage collection' to some people - that's probably what he's talking about.. "will by thread be cleaned up by the system automatically before it ends"   - so his problem is his thread is being killed when it shouldn't be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling Thread.yield() in your loop to allow the system to do other things?  If not- then android could be killing the thread for consuming 100% CPU usage - if it's a simple loop the stack-trace won't change so it will thing your script hung

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()

Yield() tells the thread-executor that it should stop and run other threads before returning to yours, without it your loop will steal resources from other apps

You can also sleep if you are sure your flag won't change for a certain amount of time

**Edit -  Background** -  it's the way android detects hung threads - If a thread takes up 100% of the CPU then it dumps a stack trace to a file, waits a short amount of time and then dumps another stack trace - if the two match it assumes the code has stopped running and will either issue an ANR 'xx is not responsing' dialog for an activity, OR, if it's a service, it will simply kill it and restart it automatically.

By yielding you prevent it from consuming 100% so it never tries to do that.

Comment: I'll try yield() later. Maybe this is the reason. And by recycling I mean 'garbage collection'.

Comment: Note: it is NOT the garbage collector that is doing this!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what your code is doing, and even what you think should be happening.  However there is one thing that we can clear up right away.

Threads in Java (and Android) do not "recycle".  Once a Thread's `run()` method has ended (by returning, or by allowing some exception to propagate), it won't ever restart.  Not ever.

Also, Threads are not garbage collected while they are still running.  Garbage collection cannot cause a thread to end.

Comment: Recycling means 'garbage collection' to some people - that's probably what he's talking about.. "will by thread be cleaned up by the system automatically"

Comment: Recycling means 'garbage collection'. The code isn't in this computer. I'll try @RobertMaysJr 's way first. If it doesn't work, I will show the code. thank you any way

Comment: Thought so based on the context :-)  I see why @StephenC thought it could be "reusing" a thread though...  I guess it all depends on how you recycle  (the new curbside pickup where you throw it in a different trash can versus the old-school method of simply reusing stuff yourself ) ;-)

Comment: @westlinkin - 1) GC is not the cause of your problem; see my updated answer  2) It would help if you used conventional Java terminology.  3) Recycling (in the storage management sense) in Java actually means putting an object into an object pool to PREVENT it from being garbage collected.  (And in fact it is actually worthwhile to do this with threads, though it changes the way that you use them.)

Comment: @StephenC English is not my mother tongue, I learn Java and Android in Chinese. I am sorry to confuse you. :)

Comment: @StephenC - It's not even java that is the problem here - it's the way android detects hung threads - If a thread takes up 100% of the CPU then it dumps a stack trace to a file, waits a short amount of time and then dumps another stack trace - if the two match it assumes the code has stopped running and will either issue an ANR 'xx is not responsing' dialog or, if it's a service, it will simply kill it and restart it automatically.

Comment: @RobertMaysJr - for some reason, I'm reminded of the Monty Python Pirahna Brothers sketch ... "Vicious but fair".  :-)